# "If she didn't win" or "If she doesn't win"?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-tense

Which one is correct?

> If she didn't win an award, I'll riot.

or

> If she doesn't win an award, I'll riot.

Can someone explain what are the difference?

Answer (score 3):

"If she didn't win an award" is referring to wether or not she *did* not win an award (past tense). So for example, let's say your friend just got back from a talent show. This is when you would use this sentence--when the event has already happened.

However, let's say you wanted to say the same sentence before your friend got back from the talent show. You would say "If she *does* not (future tense) win an award, I'll riot."

The difference is in the verb tenses.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct grammatically speaking. The difference is that the first one refers to an award ceremony that took place in the past, whereas the second one refers to one that will take place in the future (near or far future)

So depending on the context, one or the other will be correct